# IOS: How to get ID3 tags from an mp3 file on Dropbox sync

Tags: ios, objective-c, mp3, dropbox-api, id3

Is there a way to get ID3 tags from **NSData** or from the **NSFileHandle** without saving another copy of the file to the disk first?

The reason I ask is I need to get the ID3 tags from mp3 files on dropbox using sync API.  The sync API returns a **DBFile** object which can give you NSData and NSFileHandle for the cached file.

AVAssetUrl and AVAsset cannot be created using NSData so this method for getting ID3 tags seems out of the question.

Or maybe someone can recommend a better way to get ID3 tags from the dropbox DBFile besides NSData and NSFileHandle.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to write the data to a file and then get a URL to that file to use when initializing your `AVAsset`.

Comment: This is what I am doing until I can find a better way.  It's slow to save the file then reload it.  Especially when there are 2,000 songs to load information for in a for-loop.  I hope there is another way.

Comment: Yeah, it appears to me that `AVAsset` requires a file, but I don't have personal experience with it.